# The entity type [TType] cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

After upgrading ef-core from version 2.1 to version 2.2 (2.2.2) I started getting an error, when I do a migration.
I created a test project, here is my code:

```
public class Root
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public MainAddress Address1 { get; set; }
        public MainAddress Address2 { get; set; }
    }

public class MainAddress
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public  SubAddress SubAddress { get; set; }
    }

public class SubAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public SubSubAddress SubSubAddress { get; set; }
}

public class SubSubAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class RootConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Root>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Root> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Roots");

            builder.HasKey(it => it.Id);

            builder.OwnsOne(root => root.Address1, address =>
            {
                address.OwnsOne(a => a.SubAddress, subAddress =>
                {
                    subAddress.OwnsOne(it => it.SubSubAddress);
                });
            });

            builder.OwnsOne(root => root.Address2, address =>
            {
                address.OwnsOne(a => a.SubAddress, subAddress =>
                    {
                        subAddress.OwnsOne(it => it.SubSubAddress);
                    });
            });
        }
    }

public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Root> Roots { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RootConfig());
        }
    }
```

so, when I do update database I getting error:
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'EFError1.Models.SubAddress' cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists.
[image]

If I use the OwnsOne 2 times nested - then all is well.
Any idea?

Comment: I was able to duplicate it even in the latest 2.2.3. Apparently EF Core bug, I would suggest reporting it to their issue tracker.

Comment: yeah, I already did. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14994